# What percentage of 316.1 million is 20 million?

Tags: percentages

I am horrible at percentages and I keep getting 15.805% as the answer to the question posed in the title, but according to others that is wrong and the answer is 6.33%. I can't wrap my head around this. Can someone please help to explain it? Thanks.:)

Edit: I got 15.805% by taking 316.1 and dividing it by 20. I thought it was the right way because I then took 20 and multiplied it by 15.805 to get 316.1

Comment: You can surely show *how* you get your answer and why you think it is the right way.

Comment: If you call the percentage $x$, then ${x\over100}\cdot 316.1=20$.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for your input. I have now done such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formulas and formulations that have already been given in the other answers. But trying to explain it intuitively:

You have a certain amount, which is called "$100\%$". Then you can compute what "$1\%$" is, by dividing the original amount by $100$. In your example, you have $316.1$, which is $100\%$, and you can divide it by $100$ to obtain $3.161$, which is $1\%$.

Now, you want to know **"how many of these $1\%$'s do fit into $20$?"**.

So you can compute $20 / 3.161$, and see that the result is $6.33\%$

<sub>(I always wondered why "calculating with percentages" was taught like it was different from "normal" calculations. It is not. It's just breaking everything down into hundredths...)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The percent value is computed by multiplying the numeric value of the ratio by 100.  To find 20 million as a percentage of 318.1 millions, first compute the ratio $20/316.1$, and then multiply by 100 
$$
\frac{20}{316.1}\times 100=6.33\%
$$

Comment: Just a slightly different take. When I teach percentages I define $\%:=\frac{1}{100}$. Then $100\%=1$ so to convert to percentage you just multiply by one aka $100\%$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $x\cdot316.1\cdot10^6=20\cdot10^6$. Now you should solve it for $x$. You will get
$$x=\dfrac{20\cdot10^6}{316.1\cdot10^6}\approx0.0632711\approx6.33\%$$